# Check constraint violation before After Update trigger fires

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, check-constraints, database-trigger

I have a table which has a `bit` column and a corresponding `datetime2` column which tracks when that flag was set:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int primary key identity,
    Processed bit not null,
    DateTimeProcessed datetime2
)
```

I've added a check constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
  ADD CHECK ((Processed = 0 AND DateTimeProcessed IS NULL) 
             OR (Processed = 1 AND DateTimeProcessed IS NOT NULL))
```

I attempted to control setting of the `DateTimeProcessed` column using an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_MyTable_AfterUpdate ON MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(UPDATE(Processed))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyTable
        SET DateTimeProcessed = CASE
            WHEN tab.Processed = 1 THEN GETDATE()
            ELSE NULL
            END
        FROM MyTable tab
        JOIN INSERTED ins
        ON ins.Id = tab.Id
    END
END
```

The problem with this is that the check constraint is enforced before the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger runs, so the constraint is violated when the `Processed` column is updated.

What would be the best way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, according to the MSDN page for [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> If a table has FOREIGN KEY or CHECK CONSTRAINTS and triggers, the constraint conditions are evaluated before the trigger is executed.

This rules out the possibility of using an "INSTEAD OF" trigger as well.

You should remove the CHECK CONSTRAINT as ultimately it is not needed since the AFTER trigger itself can provide the same enforcement of the rule:

- You are already making sure that the date field is being set upon the BIT field being set to 1.
- Your CASE statement is already handling the BIT field being set to 0 by NULLing out the date field.
- You can have another block to check on `IF UPDATE(DateTimeProcessed)` and either put it back to what it was in the `DELETED` table or throw an error.

  - If you update it back to the original value then you might need to test for recursive trigger calls and exit if it is a recursive call.
  - If you want to throw an error, just use something along the lines of:

    ```
    IF(UPDATE(DateTimeProcessed))
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR('Update of [DateTimeProcessed] field is not allowed.', 16, 1);
       ROLLBACK; -- cancel the UPDATE statement
       RETURN;
    END;
    ```

    Keep in mind that the `UPDATE()` function only indicates that the field was in the UPDATE statement; it is *not* an indication of the value changing. Hence, doing an UPDATE wherein you `SET DateTimeProcessed = DateTimeProcessed` would clearly not change the value but would cause `UPDATE(DateTimeProcessed)` to return "true".
  - You can also handle this portion of the "rule" outside of a trigger by using a column-level [DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx):

    `DENY UPDATE ON MyTable (DateTimeProcessed) TO {User and/or Role};`

Comment: "The comment that suggested the "BEFORE" trigger was probably deleted due to SQL Server not having a "BEFORE" trigger"...Yeah, that would probably be the reason, wouldn't it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Throwing an error if `DateTimeProcessed` is directly updated seems like the final piece to add here.

Comment: @grin0048 : Yes, I had suggested throwing an error in that scenario, is that what you were referring to or had you not seen my update? Regardless, I updated again to rearrange the order of the bullets and added some details, such as the code to handle the error and cancellation as well as a new (and lesser-known) option that doesn't involve code.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to your suggestion--just noting which one I found most helpful. Thanks again!